# I'm adding a Picklist on my LWC, but it renders as a Multi-Select Picklist. Issue on 'Line 11'

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CaseProduct__c" density="compact" record-type-id="0120C000000AyCIQA0">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>

        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                <span>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Case__c" value={CaseRecordId}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
    <!--Line 11-->  <lightning-input-field field-name="Business_Unit__c" required>  <!--Line 11-->
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Type__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Sub_Type__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Delivered_By__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Description__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </span>

            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                <span>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Requirement_Type__c" class="slds-m-top_xx-large" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Requirement_SubType__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Term__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Transition_Included__c" required>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
              <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" variant="variant" onclick={navigateToObjectHome}></lightning-button>
              <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-left_x-small" type="button" variant="brand" label="Test Next" onclick={doTestNext}></lightning-button>
              <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-left_x-small" type="button" variant="brand" label="Save and New" onclick={doSaveAndNew}></lightning-button>
          </div>

    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

...

[image: field renders incorrectly]

[image: Field is a picklist]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to import

`import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';`
 in your JS File

Here is the example I used for picklist type

JS File-

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';

export default class WireGetPicklistValues extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA',
        fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
    })
    picklistValues;
}
```

HTML File -

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="WireGetPicklistValues" icon-name="custom:custom67">
        <template if:true={picklistValues.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={picklistValues.data.values} for:item="item">
                    <lightning-input
                        key={item.value}
                        label={item.label}
                        data-value={item.value}
                        type="checkbox"
                    >
                    </lightning-input>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
         </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Or you can try this on combobox also to give look and feel of picklist, here is the code

```
 <template if:true={picklistValues.data}>
            <lightning-combobox name="progress"
                                label="Test"
                                value={value}
                                placeholder="-Select-"
                                options={picklistValues.data.values}>
            </lightning-combobox>
```

Please try this example and let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code as follows, with a bit of CSS. This helped.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CaseProduct__c" density="compact" record-type-id="0120C000000AyCIQA0" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>



        <div class='parent'>
            <div class="child">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Case__c" value={CaseRecordId}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Business_Unit__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Type__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Sub_Type__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Delivered_By__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Description__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Requirement_Type__c" class="slds-m-top_xx-large" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Requirement_SubType__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Term__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Transition_Included__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
              <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" variant="variant" onclick={navigateToObjectHome}></lightning-button>
              <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-left_x-small" type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={storeButtonName} data-name="btnSave"></lightning-button>
          </div>

    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

CSS

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    }

  .child {
    width: 50%;
  }
```